# My PHP Site code structure is visible to my clients when they request a directory

Tags: apache-2.2, php, web-server

[A folder in My Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ew7P8.png)

- I use apache web server
- PHP on the back end
- apache is running under the user www-data
- Permission for my folders are 755

When users request a php page all is well, but when they request a folder, they are presented with my code structure, How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Options -Indexes
```

[httpd wiki with an overview of directory listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)

[Possible Options in a Directory directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

Comment: Thank you so much, I just added an extra layer of security

Comment: Its not really security. Ideally an attacker has the source code but still cannot exploit. But is does shut off plain ugly auto index.

Comment: You are very right, I just noticed that a user can request the files in the directories I do not want listed. How do i prevent this?